# extracting user attributes after overriding FoSuser

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

This is my User's class that extends the FoSUser Base User, i added nom and prenom

```
class User extends BaseUser
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // your own logic
    }
```

This is the controller

```
public function demandeBoutiqueAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User();

        $user=$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->render('GestionBoutiquesBundle:Gestion:demande_boutique.html.twig', array('user'=>$user));
    }
```

and this is the view

```
<h1>Nom:{{ usr.nom }}
    Username:{{usr.username}}
</h1>
```

And the Result i get is this, usr.nom is empty

**Nom:**

**Username: okk2**

I had no problem persisting the nom and prenom, is there anyway to extract them, except through the entity's repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$nom` field of the `User` class is `private`, so `{{ usr.nom }}` won't work (you can't access `private` and `protected` fields of an object).

If we take a look at the [`BaseUser` class](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v2.0.2/Model/User.php), we can see that the `$username` field is `protected`, so `{{ usr.username }}` shouldn't work either. But it does! Why's that?

That's because the `BaseUser` class has a [`public` method `getUsername()` on line 191](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v2.0.2/Model/User.php#L191) which returns the `$username` field.

Let's now take a look at [Twig's documentation of variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables):

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP
>   layer:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid property;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid method (even if `bar` is the constructor - use `__construct()` instead);
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `getBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `isBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `hasBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, return a `null` value.
>
> `foo['bar']` on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, return a `null` value.

So, when you use `{{ usr.username }}` in Twig, you don't actually access the `protected` field `$username` (you can't because it's not `public`). Instead, Twig uses the `getUsername()` method behind the scenes.

So, to make `{{ usr.nom }}` work, add this method to your `User` class:

```
public function getNom() {
    return $this->nom;
}
```

Twig will then first try to access the `$nom` field, but it can't because the field is `private`. Instead, Twig will use the `getNom()` method and thus `{{ usr.nom }}` should work.